# Structure the Settings file

Tags: c#, settings.settings

Is it possible to divide a Settings file more? Currently this is what I have:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyModule_SomeField
Properties.Settings.Default.OtherModule_SomeField
```

I would like something more like this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyModule.SomeField
Properties.Settings.Default.OtherModule.SomeField
```

Comment: As far as i know, you can have only set of setting for project `ProjectName.Properties.Settings`, and setting.designer.cs, has code to get instance of that set of setting, so there can not be like you wanted.

Comment: Do you mean like [Create custom section in config file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226711/create-custom-section-in-config-file)?